# Adding Orchard shape to specific zone through controller action

Tags: c#, controller, orchardcms, zone

I am having a tough time adding a shape to a specific zone in my custom theme.
What I am trying to achieve is,

- Added a controller action that gets triggered on the home page url. 'Themed' attribute is assigned to controller action.
- In this controller action, I added a shape using IWorkContextAccessor and   specified the zone in which I want to render the shape.

Problems/Challenges:

- If my controller action is of return type 'void', then nothing gets rendered.
- Changing controller action return type to 'ActionResult', the shape gets rendered in the desired zone but the view associated with the controller action also gets rendered. As a workaround, I have to declare an empty view for my controller action (which seems like an overhead).

Here is my controller action code.

Code with return type ActionResult

```
    [Themed]
    public ActionResult HomePageSideZone()
    {

        string test = "This is text.";
        _workContextAccessor.GetContext()
            .Layout
            .Zones["column2_tab4"]
            .Add(_shapeFactory.MyShape(Text: test));
        return View("CargillHomePageSizeZone", _shapeFactory.CargillHomePageSizeZone(Text: test));



    }
```

Code with return type Void

```
    [Themed]
    public void HomePageSideZone()
    {

        string test = "This is text.";
        _workContextAccessor.GetContext()
            .Layout
            .Zones["column2_tab4"]
            .Add(_shapeFactory.MyShape(Text: test));




    }
```

I do not intend to use 'Placement' file as i want to use code to achieve this functionality.

Comment: An empty view is the way to go. It's what you want, from what you've described of the scenario. Another way would be to use widgets, maybe, depending on what your scenario really is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BertrandLeRoy. I am able to use an empty view and render the shape in desired zone.
However, i was wondering if there is any way to return a shape result from controller action and specify the zone in the shape result using IShapeFactory?
I also acknowledge using widgets, however, I want to keep the number of widgets to as low as possible as it effects the performance of the website.

Comment: You could easily create your own `ActionResult` that abstracts that away.
I'm intrigued by that thing about widget performance. Under what conditions? Did you profile it?

Comment: I believe it's the way widgets are pulled ro render on the front-end.
Say if there are total 50 widgets in the cms, but only 2 are set for home page, then instead of pulling just 2 widgets, the system would make conditional checks on all 50 widgets and then take out the ones assigned for home page.
another instance where performance is impacted is that if I use a custom module, then the Editor function is triggered twice, once for displayType = summary and once for displayType=detail. Same applies for Display function.

@BertrandLeRoy

Comment: Actually no, that's not how it works. Do you have evidence of a performance problem, or is this conjecture? If you have evidence, can you please file a bug?

Comment: Hi @BertrandLeRoy, I noticed this behavior when I attached a debugger to the driver functions. That is the only proof that I have.
To elaborate on this, on using projections, this behavior is amplified. The reason for this is say there are 10 items listed in a projection. Each item has a custom content part, then the display function in driver would be invoked twice (once for summar and once for detail). Therefore calling the display function in driver 20 times. I would say try it out by adding a debug point.

Comment: That code gets run a lot does not necessarily make it a perf bottleneck. Profile it if you really want to know what's going on.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I appreciate your prompt feedback. 
The big question here is, why would this behavior happen?
Why would a projection need to call the driver functions for every item that is fetched by the projection?

Comment: Because that's what drivers are for: changing the content part data into shapes that are ready to be rendered.